# JQuery Appending an item only if it has already been detached

Tags: jquery

So I have an element that loads in only if the site is above a certain width (768), and I can get it to detach and reappend on resize. However it throws a lot of errors if I resize up before I detach.
This is the code that works but throws errors

```
$(function(){
    var $window = $(window),
        $html = $('html'),
        $putter;
function resize(){
    if ($window.width() < 769){
        $putter = $('.header_box').detach();
    } else if ($window.width() >= 769){
        $putter.appendTo('#nt_tool');
    }

}
$window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');

});
```

When I try to check for the already detached item being there it stops working. It will still detach but it will no longer append.

```
$(function(){
var $window = $(window),
    $html = $('html'),
    $putter;
function resize(){
    if ($window.width() < 769){
        $putter = $('.header_box').detach();
    } else if (($window.width() >= 769) && ($putter !== null)){
        $putter.appendTo('#nt_tool');
    }

}
$window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');

});
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendTo' of undefined
```

Comment: maybe the problem is in:
&& ($putter !== null)

could you past the errors?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the item to be detached to the variable declaration fixed the issue and removed the necessity of checking for the stored variable in the append step. Functioning code below.

```
$(function(){
var $window = $(window),
    $html = $('html'),
    $putter = $('.header_box');
function resize(){
    if ($window.width() < 769){
        $putter.detach();
    } else if ($window.width() >= 769){
        $putter.appendTo($('#nt_tool'));
    }
}
$window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');

});
```